# Is there a concise expression for 'as it exists today'?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Especially in the context of a situation that is anticipated to change in the near future.

As in:

> An analysis of the subway system capacity, both as it exists today and after upcoming expansions.

Or:

> This document surveys the ethnic makeup of Manhattan, both historically and as it exists today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### As it exists today

The most obvious choice to substitute “as it exists today” is [*contemporary*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contemporary) (sense 2) or [*present-day*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/present-day), but those are not very elegant as adverbs. I would probably rephrase it a bit:

> This document surveys the ethnic making of Manhattan, both historical and contemporary.
>   This document surveys the ethnic making of (both) historical and contemporary Manhattan.
>   This document surveys the ethnic making of (both) historical and present-day Manhattan.

— or just do what @ErikKowal suggests and use *today*, which is perfectly valid, even if it is less prolix.

#### After upcoming expansions

Obviously, *contemporary* or *present-day* will not work to describe a situation that has not yet arisen but is expected to after upcoming expansions.

This situation is really just describing a *future* situation, but it is also quite specific in that it mentions a specific set of expansions to be carried out. There is no way of simplifying that to a single word or expression—just use what you already have.

If you are looking for something to describe all three points in time (historical, now, and in the future) and don’t care too much about the details of the expansions, you could say:

> An analysis of the subway system capacity, (both) **past, present, and future**.

(Note that some people consider *both* in such a sentence to be ungrammatical, claiming that *both* must be followed by exactly two options, not three. If you are writing a formal text, it is probably best to leave it out; but to me at least, leaving it in yields a much more natural sentence.)

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it just be **current(ly)**.

Answer (score 0):

"... both historically and today".

Comment: While it's a better way to say the whole thing that's not a _concise expression for 'as it exists today'_

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

> This document surveys the ethnic makeup of Manhattan, both historically and *contemporarily*.

[**contemporary**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contemporary): happening or beginning now or in recent times; existing or happening in the same time period: from the same time period.